# dnsmasq as authoritative DNS server with synth domain

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dnsmasq

I have a fair amount of DNS experience, however, I've never setup my own DNS server (I've always used 3rd parties); this is my first time trying to run my own DNS service.

My desired setup:

- authoritative dns server
- synth (artificial) domain responses
- no query forwarding (ideally, it should *silently* drop any queries that it is not authoritative for)
- ability to add other records (A, AAAA, PTR, MX ..etc)

AFAIK, only dnsmasq supports synth domains (which is the main reason to setup this auth sever). I'm not concerned with how to actually host the service, I am trying to validate the dnsmasq configuration at this point.

I spent a while looking at the [man pages](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) and I can't seem to actually get an auth dnsmasq server to operate the way I would like. For example, I'm trying to do a proof of concept config:

```
auth-server=ns1.example.com,lo0
auth-zone=example.com
synth-domain=example.com,192.168.1.0/24,ip-
```

This is running locally, so to test:

```
$ dig @127.0.0.1 ip-192-168-1-100.example.com +short
$
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like it's normal `dnsmasq` behavior. I found [old thread](http://dnsmasq-discuss.thekelleys.org.narkive.com/mwXvtapZ/mixing-synth-domain-and-auth-domain-does-not-appear-to-work-for-me), where described why `synth-domain` and `auth-zone` not working together. After commenting `auth-zone` in configuration files, everything start working.

Comment: Good find! Looks like I'll have to look elsewhere to get everything I'm looking for.